# simple angularjs app view not loading

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get into angularJS by writing the most basic app. However I'm unable to get even this small amount of code working - the controller doesn't seem to be displaying any of the views. This is almost a direct copy from a popular angularjs video I saw online. I have a feeling its not something big, and my guess is that I possibly have something wrong with the ng-view.

Any insight on what I'm doing wrong would be helpful.

## index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="fastsql">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="well">
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>


<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="fastsql.js"></script>  

</body>
</html>
```

## fastsql.js

```
// setup fastsql as angular app "module"
var fastsql = angular.module("fastsql", []);

// set routeProvider rules in .config()
fastsql.config(function($routeProvider) {

// set what views are displayed for each change in the URL.
$routeProvider
.when("/", { controller: 'loginCntl', templateURL: 'test.html' })
.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

});

// controllers
fastsql.controller("loginCntl", function($scope) { $scope.message = "hey"; });
```

Answer (score 8):

`templateURL` should have been `templateUrl`.

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass an array into the config function, the name of the services to injected, and then the function in to which they are injected.

```
fastsql.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
 // do your thing
}]);
```

Comment: I did try adding this earlier, with no avail. Just tried it another time and it's still not displaying any views :(

Is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: i'm not sure, check this plnkr - it's basically the same as yours and it works: http://plnkr.co/edit/ziNS05uxdgzwQMN6dG3V?p=preview

Comment: Got it! templateURL should have been templateUrl. The rest works, deff would have been stuck at it for forever without your help. Thanks so much!

Comment: glad to help, and you can mark it as the answer and/or vote it up.